# Why pulseaudio is reported as not running?

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, soundcard

I have `Ubuntu 21.10` and I get the below results related to `pulseaudio`.
What should I do to "connect" to `pulseaudio` such that `pacmd list-sinks` to correctly report something?

```bsh
$sudo netstat -tlupn | egrep -i "mopidy|pulse"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4713            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1730/pulseaudio
tcp6       0      0 :::4713                 :::*                    LISTEN      1730/pulseaudio

$pacmd list-sinks
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.

$ps -ef | egrep "/[p]ulseaudio"
lightdm     1730    1668  0 Oct30 ?        00:04:35 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
```